# Only use the Object when we want a map in javascript,is it ok or better?

Tags: javascript

simple demo:

```
var Map = function() {
    var fakeMap = {};
    this.put = function(key,obj){
        fakeMap[key]=obj;
    };
    this.get = function(key){
        return fakeMap[key];
    };
};

var map = new Map();
map.put('key1','val1');
map.put('func1',function(){
    return 'this is func1';
});

alert(map.get('key1'));
alert(map.get('func1')());
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/NyLWm/

so in js map can be implemented like this?

Comment: I guess, but why would you want to?

Comment: So what's wrong with `map = {};`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems more JavaScript-y to me (mostly because we drop the classical "new" syntax):

```
function map () {
    var cache = {};
    return {
        put : function (key, val) {
            cache[key] = val;
        },
        get : function (key) {
            return cache[key];
        }
    };
}

var m = map();
m.put('key1','val1');
m.put('func1',function(){
    return 'this is func1';
});

alert(m.get('key1'));
alert(m.get('func1')());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's almost correct. But if you want a good implementation, you will also have to modify your get function to something like this:

```
get: function(key) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( fakeMap, key )) ? fakeMap[key] : undefined;
}
```

If you don't do this, all properties in Object.prorotype will become a part of the Map. Ie, if you try to do a `map.get("toString")`, you will get a value even though you didn't put anything. You could have used `fakeMap.hasOwnProperty(key)`, but then if you do a `map.put("hasOwnProperty", "something")` then a following map.get would result in an error.