# Javascript/ Jquery Select object based on nested attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to retrieve a nested object based on a nested nested id.

So my object is as follows

```
object = {
   1: {
      feature: {id:"1012"},
   }
   2: {
      feature: {id:"3032"}
   }
}
```

I have an id and I need to retrieve the corresponding object or to be more specific the object id. The object is a lot more complex but above shows the values that I need to retrieve.

I don't have much experience in JavaScript so am unsure how to achieve this. I've tried using Jquery's attribute selectors but have not been successful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That looks like a syntax error. Could you please post a valid JavaScript object literal, or a JSON representation of your object?

Comment: Assuming javaScript objects, you would like to retrieve entire object if one of the ID matches or return only the specific key say 1 or 2?

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up --> I would like to retrieve the specific key preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your "id" is mean like 1 or 2
do it like this:[view it in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5AE2/)

```
    var obj = {
       1: {
          feature: {id:"1012"}
       },
       2: {
          feature: {id:"3032"}
       }
    }

    var getById = function(id){
        return obj[id];
    }

    alert(getById(1).feature.id);
```

another way,if your id means like '1012','3032'

do it like this:[view it in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQrZ9/)

[my post about the Map in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212970/only-use-the-object-when-we-want-a-map-in-javascript-is-it-ok-or-better)

Comment: Sorry, I mean the other way round -- So I'll provide the ID and then I'll get given the object ID.

Comment: Give me some examples.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly you are trying to use the `id` property of the object in each `feature` property to get the key (1, 2, etc) from `object`? So if you entered `"1012"` you would get back `1`, if you entered `"3032"` you would get `2`, etc?

If so this would do it:

```
var object = {
     1: {
        feature: {id:"1012"}
     },
     2: {
        feature: {id:"3032"}
     }
  },
  getIdByFeatureId = function (featureId) {
    var id,
      subObject;
    // loop through each property of the object
    for (id in object) {
      // protect ourselves in case someone has tampered with Object.prototype
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        subObject = object[id];
        if (subObject.feature.id === featureId) {
          return id;
        }
      }
    }

    // none found? return null.
    return null;
  };

getIdByFeatureId("3032"); // returns 2
getIdByFeatureId("1012"); // returns 1
getIdByFeatureId("90210"); // returns null
```

You can play with the code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/gfBQt/).

Numbers stored as strings can be a pain, and often lead to confusion in how one need to call a function like this. One thing you might notice is I used the `===` strict equal operator. This only returns true if both values are exactly the same, including their type. It's good practice to use strict comparison operators unless you absolutely can't. It is also slightly faster since it doesn't have to coerce the values into a like type. But that means that you must pass a string into the function in order for it to match. You could use the non-strict equals `==` if you need it to be more flexible. If all of the feature ids are numeric (and none of them have leading zeros) and you have the ability to, I would change the feature ids to be actual numbers so you can keep it more intuitive by just passing in a number instead of a string representation of a number: `getIdByFeatureId(3032);` while keeping the strict comparison.